# ASP.NET detect website first run

Tags: asp.net, session

I use user IP to find his location for displaying the correct content in my ASP.NET website. I set a session at the start of my default.aspx page to detect whether it is the first time my user runs website or not, if it is the first time, my location detection algorithm runs and city session is set as well. My users can change city and each time they change city, the city session is changed also. This process works fine, but when user closes his browser, and again opens browser my city detection algorithm doesn't run because my `session["firsttime"]` is still active and its value is `TRUE` (my session lifetime is set to its default 20 minutes). How can I detect that user has just started his browser even if he has a `session["firsttime"]` set to `TRUE`?

Can I do it using global.asax file?

Comment: which session mode are you using ?

Comment: mhhh, if the user close the browser next time he goes to your site `session["firsttime"]` should be null for him.

Comment: I'm using inProc mode, of course session remains up to its lifetime (20 mins here), so my algorithm doesn't run again in this period, can I use Session_Start in global.asax.cs? when does it run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using **cookies** instead of Session to **detect the "first time" & "returning user"**. Also, you can set the Location Info in cookie.

Comment: thanks, but would you please clarify your solution? what should I exactly set in my cookies? how long should my cookies last?